# MySQL grouping and assembling

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create something as the following:

1-I need to have top level item, mid level item, low level item.

2-A mid level item can consists of low level items, or is simply a stand alone item

3-a top level item consists of mid level items.

For example:

Top level item:
1- Mid level item1.
2- Mid level item2.
3- Mid level item3:
1- low level item1.
2- low level item2.
4- Mid level item 4.

Any help on how to create data bases that are connected in such way using mysql or is there a better db to use than mysql for this kind of needs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table which references itself. Item with `parent_id = NULL` is a top level item.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_id` INT NULL,
    <other fields like name or something else>
);

ALTER TABLE `item`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_PARENT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `item` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
;
```